# How do I create pairs from a data frame given constraints found in another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I need to randomly match two staff emails from a list of emails. The staff pairs **can not** have the same managers and **can not** have been paired before. Best way to go about achieving this? I'm not that great with Python so not even sure how to start. The other similar questions I found didn't help me much.

I have two datasets:

1. List of active members
   Column A: Emails of staff
   Column B: The staff's manager

   ```
   Emails             Managers
   jessica@xyz.com    Bob
   alex@xyz.com       Justin
   lucy@xyz.com       Justin
   eric@xyz.com       Zach
   brandon@xyz.com    Tony
   dylan@xyz.com      Patty
   ```
2. List of historical matches

   ```
   Emails             Managers
   lucy@xyz.com       Justin
   eric@xyz.com       Zach
   ```

What it might look like:

```
    Emails1            Managers1    Emails2            Managers2
    dylan@xyz.com      Patty        lucy@xyz.com       Justin
    eric@xyz.com       Zach         brandon@xyz.com    Tony
    ...
```

What I have so far (lol):

```
# Dependencies and Setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

# Load file and read in the data
active_data = pd.read_csv("Active.csv")
historical_data = pd.read_csv("Historical.csv")

# Preview data
active_data.head(7)
```

[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9SgH.jpg)

[dtypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKdte.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works or not

```
df['if_duplicate'] = df.duplicated(subset=['managers'])
unique_incdices = [x for x in df.shape[0] if df.loc[x,'if_duplicated']==False]

unique_incdices = [x for x in unique_incdices if x not in historical_matches['emails'].values]
ab = np.random.randint(0,len(unique_incdices),size=2)
i,j = unique_incdices[ab[0]],unique_incdices[ab[1]]

i and j are indices of two rows who
```

Comment: I get "NameError: name 'df' is not defined" for the first line.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Got this error now "KeyError: Index(['managers'], dtype='object')"

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of trace? I will get back to you in like an hour

Comment: What is the datatype of names in Managers columns in the active dataframe?

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question and added the pictures. Managers is an object.

Comment: Why do they have to be objects? Can they not be simply strings of names and emails for this problem specifically because otherwise, you will have to implement  custom functions to handle objects equality and comparison

Comment: They don't have to be objects. Should I use str() to convert them to string? How do I implement that into your code above?

Comment: or use apply(str)?

Comment: I don't understand why you would stringify object and then compare it. Simply, using object.name should be good.